# Boot into Safari-only mode in Mountain Lion?

Tags: macos, safari, startup

In Lion, you used to be able to boot into a Safari-only mode. Where did that go in Mountain Lion?

Answer (score 1):

In Mountain Lion, Safari-only mode was replaced by a full guest account, however you can get it back by **enabling FileVault 2**.